# Use jQuery Mobile + GWT UIBinder

Tags: jquery, gwt, mobile, responsive-design

I wanna use jQuery Mobile with existing GWT-apps. This works pretty neat so far, I've successfully integrated the external JS-files by the use of the ScriptInjector-class and am therefore able to access certain functionalities. The basic app looks nice and "responsive" on mobile devices.

But unfortunately, there's still some trouble with that. I wanna use the jQuery-buttons instead of my custom ones that're in use so far and dunno how to realize that...

I've considered implementing a hidden div/element on the index.html that get's dynamically displayed as well as integrating the external CSS-file to the UIBinder, but don't know how to realize this. How do I access elements on the index.html?

Something like `<a href="index.html" data-role="button" data-icon="info">Button</a>` for a button works perfectly well when it's implemented in the index.html, but not from the UiBinder-XML.

Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've more or less solved this by a fair use of the JSNI as well as some other tweaks, such as the mentioned access to GWT anchors. The key here is to use `$wnd.jQuery` instead of `$` when making native calls.

I didn't wanna use an external library.

Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check out [gwtquery](http://code.google.com/p/gwtquery/)?
It's jQuery like API written in GWT. 
The good thing is that it works natively in GWT and only the part that is really used will end up in the compiled code.
With jQuery always the whole library is included.

To your original question. You can simply embed normal HTML elements like a Anchor in UiBinder (you have to place it inside a `HTMLPanel` tough. Use Firebug or Developer Tools to check the output